# AWS POST to API Gateway returning a 415 "Unsupported Media Type"

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, aws-amplify

I'm currently trying to set up an API Gateway proxy call directly to my DynamoDB table.  I've set everything up so that the test from the API Gateway console returns the expected result:

```
{
  "Items": [
    {
      "zoneID": "Northern",
      "location": "Pro Skate Shop",
      "address": "123 Fake Street",
      "exposureDate": "04/06/2021",
      "exposureWindow": "16:00 - 17:30",
      "advice": "get tested immediately"
    }
   ]
 }
```

And if I `curl` my endpoint, I'm also getting the expected response:

```
$ curl -X POST https://<API URL>/dev/getcontacts
{
    "Items": [
         {
            "zoneID": "Northern",
            "location": "Pro Skate Shop",
            "address": "123 Fake Street",
            "exposureDate": "04/06/2021",
            "exposureWindow": "16:00 - 17:30",
            "advice": "get tested immediately"
          }
     ]
  }
```

However, when I call from my app:

```
export function GetContacts() {
    const [contacts, setContacts] = useState([]);

    const url = '/getcontacts'

    useEffect(() => {
        async function callApi() {
            try {
                const contactList = await API.post('testapi', url)
                console.log("results: ", contactList)
                setContacts(contactList.Items)
            } catch (err) { console.log({err})}
        }
        if (contacts.length === 0) {
            callApi()
        }
    }, [contacts, url])
```

I get the following error in my console:

`Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 415 ()`

I'm assuming this just has something to do with the request headers (it's being sent as `application/json`) but I'm really not certain how to troubleshoot this.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Use `JSON.stringify`

Comment: Where should I be using it?